# Different product auth with openldap group

Tags: ldap, gitlab, openldap, zabbix

I hava gitlab、zabbix and some other products. I want sign in these products with one username and password but different group. So, i can crontrol who can sign in the specify product.

For example:
user A can sign in gitlab,zabbix
user B only can sign in gitlab
user C only can sign in zabbbix

How can i make it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LDAP groups for this. You will find enough resources in the Internet. Feel free to come back to StackOverflow with a specific question later.